# Is there a internal server in visual studio code editor other than configuring nodejs server in launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

While debugging code locally using microsoft visual studio code  editor, Is there any local server like Adobe's bracket editor instead of configuring nodejs server in **launch.json** ?

```
launch.json: {
     "configurations": [
         {
            "name": "Launch server on port",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "src/server/server.js",
            "args": ["--port=8080"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
            "address": "localhost",
            // Port to attach to.
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    ]}
```

**Reference:*** https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging